# how to check whether a given string is between particular time range

Tags: android, date, kotlin, time

Given start string like "09:00" and end string like "10:00" how do i check whether current time is between this range or not. I have searched a lot but most of them requires a higher API level and my minimum android target version is 20. Please suggest some code in Kotlin.

```
fun Date.toString(format: String, locale: Locale = Locale.getDefault()): String {
        val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(format, locale)
        return formatter.format(this)
    }

    fun getCurrentDateTime(): Date {
        return Calendar.getInstance().time
    }

    val date = getCurrentDateTime()
    val currentDate = date.toString("dd/MM/yyyy")
    val currentTime: String = date.toString("HH:mm")
```

this is how i have managed to get date and time

Comment: If the time strings strictly follow this format (with 24-hour time format) then simply comparing the strings should be enough.

Comment: On Android API level 20 add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your project and use the answers you have found that use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. In this way you can avoid the old and poorly designed `Calendar` and not least `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Also keeping your start and end times as strings is a poor idea. Keep `LocalTime` objects instead. Their `isBefore` and/or `isAfter` method will be handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.

create method/function like this,

```
private fun checkCurrentTimeIsBetweenGivenString(s1:String,s2:String): Boolean{

        val simpleDateFormat= SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")

        val date1:Date=simpleDateFormat.parse(s1)

        val date2:Date=simpleDateFormat.parse(s2)

        val d= Date()

        val s3=simpleDateFormat.format(d)

        val date3=simpleDateFormat.parse(s3)

        return  date3 >= date1  &&  date3 <= date2
    }
```

Use Like This,

```
if(checkCurrentTimeIsBetweenGivenString("16/10/2019 10:00","16/10/2019 12:00")){
            Log.e("output","Current time is between this range")
        }else{
            Log.e("output","Current time is not between this range")
        }
```

if the current time is between a given string then if the part will work, if not else part will work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution it really works but I am facing some problem which i have explained in edit. Please look into that

Answer (score 1):

i thing this will work

```
 private fun checkDate(startDate: String, endDate: String): Boolean {
    val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
    val dateStart: Date = simpleDateFormat.parse(startDate)
    val dateEnd: Date = simpleDateFormat.parse(endDate)
    val currentDate = Date()
    return currentDate.after(dateStart) && currentDate.before(dateEnd)
 }
```

example :

```
if (checkDate("16/10/2019 05:13", "16/12/2019 09:12")) {
     //Date is between range
} else {
     //Date is not between range
}
```

if current time is between range return true otherwise return false, Please check

Answer (score 1):

```
fun checkIfInRangeOfHours(startHour: String, endHour: String): Boolean {
    val currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().time
    val currentDate = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).format(currentTime)
    val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm", Locale.ENGLISH)
    val startDate: Date? = simpleDateFormat.parse("$currentDate $startHour")
    val endDate: Date? = simpleDateFormat.parse("$currentDate $endHour")
    return Date().after(startDate) && Date().before(endDate)
}
```